# How to resolve this `t9n` translations error when I use its `plural` property?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, mt940, t9

I am trying to translate some text using `t9n` library, but I get this error

```
Compiling...
Error compiling ICU message for locale en-US: SyntaxError: Expected "=", "}", or identifier but "," found.

To debug this set DEBUG_ICU to 'true'
```

when I use this piece of code in React JS

```
`t9n("{count, plural, one {one other}, others {# others}}", { count: userIds.length - 1 })`;
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of errors comma should not be there before `others` and `others` should be `other`. Also we can change `{one other}` to `{# other}` as this is more optimal.

```
`t9n("{count, plural, one {# other} other {# others}}", { count: userIds.length - 1 });`
```